# Split an existing CAT5 Cable into a Y cable without using a switch?

Tags: cabling, cable

I have a long cable coming from my other room and I want to connect this cable to a raspberry pi and my laptop. I know I can just get a basic switch to solve this problem.

But is there such a thing as a Y cable for CAT5? I don't care if it reduces my speed to 10mbit or less. This Y cable would have to be female on one end and then output to 2 male cat5 cables.

How can this work? If not, how come?

Comment: No, you can't do that. UTP cannot have splices or splits. Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su], but this type of thing has been asked there before, so you may want to search the site first.

Comment: In theory You can build Hub from diodes https://www.eeweb.com/blog/circuit_projects/building-a-passive-ethernet-hub or small resistors, and force 100 Mbits Half-Duplex mode. But much simpler and better set cheap unmanaged switch http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-5-ports-RJ-45-10-100-1000-Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Switch-Auto-MDI-MDIX-Hub-/282049869796?hash=item41ab7b77e4:g:9gMAAOSwa81XRrHr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do it.

Unlike an audio or cable TV cable, UTP Ethernet has a transmit pair of wires and a receive pair. If you were to combine the transmit pair from two devices, the signals would interfere with each other and the receiver on the other end would be unable to decode the signals.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Cat5 is normally 4-Pair: Each Ethernet conection requires only 2 pair. You can easily run 2 2-pair Ethernet connections through1 4-pair Cat5! It works fine. But if you split an existing CAT5 Cable into a Y cable, then the result is that you're unable to connect to your network and can't get on the Internet.If you really want to do it, get a switch or fix the wireless settings.

Comment: Gigabit Ethernet requires all four pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to run two Ethernet lines down one four-pair cat 5 cable. There are some caveats though.

1. You will need a splitter box/cable at both ends of the cable run and two seperate ports on the existing hub/switch.
2. This will work for 10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX but not for 1000BASE-T.
3. POE may not work depending on the particular POE implementation in use.

Comment: Why down voting? There are 4 pairs in the cable and we need just 2, so yes, it is possible and I did it few times in my life ;)